# ignore function in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

on page 95 of the book titled developing applications with objective caml

```
let imap f l =  
let l_res = icreate ()  
in while not (iempty l) do  
     ignore (icons (f (ihd l)) l_res) ;  
     ignore (itl l)
   done ;
   { l_res with c = List.rev l_res.c } ;;
```

What does the ignore function do in the above coding?
I was able to get the same result without the ignore function implemented in 
the while loop as follows:

```
let imap f l =  
let l_res = icreate ()  
in while not (iempty l) do  
     (icons (f (ihd l)) l_res) ;  
     (itl l)
   done ;
   { l_res with c = List.rev l_res.c } ;;
```

Then the book goes on and says that The presence of ignore emphasizes the fact that it is not the result of the functions that counts here, but their side effects on their argument.

if the result of the functions does not count, then how does the while loop stop?
In this case, it seems to me that the while loop will loop continuously if the result of
(itl l) is ignored. 
Also, what side effects on their argument is the book refering to? 
Thank you

Answer (score 17):

Since the function `itl` mutates its input (in this case `l`), the `while` clause terminates when `l` is empty. I believe `itl` removes the first element of the list, so essentially you iterate over the elements of the list).

The calls to `ignore` are just for the readability: they signal to the reader that the functions are not used for their output -- so they must have some desired side effect.

EDIT: the call to ignore may also help eliminate compiler warnings (see [the manual](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Stdlib.html#VALignore)):

```
val ignore : 'a -> unit
```

> Discard the value of its argument and return (). For instance, ignore(f x) discards the result of the side-effecting function f. It is equivalent to f x; (), except that the latter may generate a compiler warning; writing ignore(f x) instead avoids the warning.

Comment: ignore can be implemented as: `let ignore v = let _ = v in ()` fyi.  In fact, before I learned about `ignore` I would do that to get rid of compiler warnings.

Comment: is one preferred over the other? IOW, is `let _ = ...` preferred over `ignore (...)` or the other way around WRT style/idiomatic reasons?